# Rails 3: Create an instance with 3 foreign keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Having a reviews table:

```
# Table name: reviews
#
#  id          :integer         not null, primary key
#  wsp_id      :integer
#  service_id  :integer
#  user_id     :integer
#  description :text
#  rating      :integer
#  created_at  :datetime
#  updated_at  :datetime
#

  belongs_to :wsp
  belongs_to :service
  belongs_to :user
```

How can I create a review for a service and pass the wsp_id and user_id? Do I need to use nested routes?

I am able to do `@user.reviews.new(params[:review])` but I'm not being able of passing the `wsp_id` and the `service_id`.

Here's my Reviews create controller.

```
 def create
    @review = current_user.reviews.new(params[:review]) 

    if @review.save
      #Saved
    else
      #Error, not saved
    end
  end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

routes.rb

```
resources :services do
   resources :review
end

resources :review, :only => [:create]
```

This way you will be able to create the review independently without any nesting. There is no need to read data within your form and stuff it somehow into the action url :) That's ugly but you could do it using javascript but it's basically yucky.

In your view

```
= form_for(review) do |f|
  = f.collection_select :service, Service.all
  = ..more model fields..
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried nesting the params (e.g. `params[:review][:service_id]`) and then passing `params[:review]`?

Comment: How do I get :service_id if the routes are not nested?

Comment: @donald, routes (or nested routes) are not the only way to get data. You could get the wsp_id and service_id from the session for example and merge them into the params before the create call in the create action. You need to determine the values of service_id or wsp_id from somewhere in the application and only you would know that.

Comment: @Aditya Can you please explain what other way can I use? Thanks

Comment: Commenting sucks because pressing enter sends it when i just want a new line. Is wsp_id and service_id based on user input? if they are then they would be a part of your form and the params[:review] would already contain it and you would need to do nothing. If these values can be determined based on @user then i suggest you dont do anything the new/form but simply do the determination before the create call in the create action. Please tell us how wsp_id and service_id are determined?

Comment: ..or you could just determine wsp and service in a before_save callback within the review model if your logic can do that. Tell us more :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Let's imagine someone buys a service. The service has a seller (wsp_id) and its own id. When I do the review I must know which service is being reviewed. I imagine I can let the user choose from a dropbox (like proposed above) and I'd know the service_id that way or I can nest it /service/:id/reviews/new. Hope it answers your question.

Comment: Right, if you determine service and wsp as a part of the form itself, then they are attributes of the review itself. There is NO need for you to nest it further. Your form action is going to be review_path with a post request. WSP and Service are going to be contained with the params[:review] itself since you're capturing that within the form. Your routes file needs to loosen up a bit and allow for creation of review without being nested in services and wsps. You can still have the nesting as before. Posting code..

Answer (score 0):

I kind of new to rails too...but hopefully this help.
this will add your foreign key to your model with changing any routes files

```
def new
  @anime = Anime.new
  user_id = session[:user_id]
end

def create
  @anime = Anime.new(params[:anime])
  @anime.user_id = session[:user_id]
end
```